# docker builds now failing with latest ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, docker

Old dockerfiles that run great before are all now failing now
Base ubuntu image i used for these dockerfiles is the latest 16.04 ubuntu

Here is where the builds are failing

```
Setting up libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.2-0ubuntu1) ...
No schema files found: doing nothing.
Setting up libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 (1.46.0-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-glib-2.0:amd64 (1.46.0-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up iso-codes (3.65-1) ...
Setting up krb5-locales (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libroken18-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libasn1-8-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libkrb5support0:amd64 (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libk5crypto3:amd64 (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libkeyutils1:amd64 (1.5.9-8ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libkrb5-3:amd64 (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libhcrypto4-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libheimbase1-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libwind0-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libhx509-5-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libkrb5-26-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libheimntlm0-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgssapi3-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libsasl2-modules-db:amd64 (2.1.26.dfsg1-14build1) ...
Setting up libsasl2-2:amd64 (2.1.26.dfsg1-14build1) ...
Setting up libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up librtmp1:amd64 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d-1build1) ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up libdbus-glib-1-2:amd64 (0.106-1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-data (2.48.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libicu55:amd64 (55.1-7ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libsasl2-modules:amd64 (2.1.26.dfsg1-14build1) ...
Setting up libxml2:amd64 (2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Killed
dpkg: error processing package shared-mime-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 137
Setting up xdg-user-dirs (0.15-2ubuntu6) ...
Setting up xml-core (0.13+nmu2) ...
Setting up xz-utils (5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/xz to provide /usr/bin/lzma (lzma) in auto mode
Setting up dh-python (2.20151103ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up python3 (3.5.1-3) ...
Setting up lsb-release (9.20160110ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up python-apt-common (1.1.0~beta1build1) ...
Setting up python3-apt (1.1.0~beta1build1) ...
Setting up python3-dbus (1.2.0-3) ...
Setting up python3-gi (3.20.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-pycurl (7.43.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-software-properties (0.96.20.5) ...
Setting up software-properties-common (0.96.20.5) ...
Setting up unattended-upgrades (0.90ubuntu0.3) ...

Creating config file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades with new version

Creating config file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades with new version
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20160104ubuntu1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
173 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
Processing triggers for sgml-base (1.26+nmu4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shared-mime-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Seems to always start with the `shared-mime-info` part.
Anyone one else having same issue now?

P.S. Here is what is in my Dockerfile, you can try for yourself

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository -y "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) multiverse" && \
    add-apt-repository -y "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc)-updates multiverse"
```

Comment: Your Dockerfile builds just fine over here ... perhaps you are using a local docker registry which is tainted ... if so it will build OK using a clean local registry or just default to the normal docker registry

Comment: i don't what you mean by docker registry..i am pulling the base ubuntu 16.04 image..how am i dependent on a local registry from that Dockerfile?..by the way i am building on a mac, so not sure if that affects

Comment: Pls update your question to show the working Dockerfile ... also post the OSX version you are on ... and post output of command :  docker info

Comment: i think the issue was i was running the build on Mac.
Just remembered i ran into similar issues before. Even the image build makes use of the parent host(kernel, and so on) where the build is ran, which causes issues when building an image using a new OS base on an OS that is extinct..anyways figured out the issue now

Comment: to help people reading this can you mention what OS allowed your docker build to run OK

Answer (score 0):

Happens to be because i was trying to run the build on Max OS Sierra 10.12.x. 
Since i am using base image of Ubuntu 16.04, i just went ahead to build the image on a machine with Ubuntu 16.04 and everything works.

Would be great to be able to build images without dependency on host OS, but i am not sure how possible that is. I understand running containers need the host OS but not sure how much that dependency goes with just building an image.

Anyways that solved my issue. Should have known as this happened before where i had to go build image on another machine and OS.